# Create new file or overwrite existing one with Files.newBufferedWriter in Java 7

Tags: java, file, java-7

I am giving a try to the new Files.newBufferedWriter in Java 7 and I can't get an example to work: I want to create a new file if it doesn't exist or overwrite it if it does.

What I do is:

```
OpenOption[] options = {StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING};
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("example.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, options);
```

I tried also with different options, but I can't get it to work.

Help?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [documentation of this function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) already says us that:

`newBufferedWriter(Path path, Charset cs, OpenOption... options)`

The options parameter specifies how the the file is created or opened. If **no options are present** then this method works as if the `CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE` options are present. In other words, **it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of 0 if it exists.**

So you could just do without passing an option:

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("example.txt"), 
                                                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, it throws NoSuchFileException